# How to get information from JSON API

Tags: jquery, json

Here is the JSON API, for example do you see at the bottom Under the Members there is a Member called Olehead and his "channel_id":"377799006849466380", Which matches the channel called RANKED (50K) #2 (same ID), How would I be able to write a code to Display the number of people connected to that channel and output it into HTML?.

Regards!,

```
 {  
"channels":[  
  {  
     "position":6,
     "id":"377806110331240449",
     "name":"RANKED (10K) #1"
  },
  {  
     "position":8,
     "id":"377806225343250433",
     "name":"RANKED (10K) #2"
  },
  {  
     "position":7,
     "id":"377806225896898562",
     "name":"RANKED (10K) #2"
  },
  {  
     "position":3,
     "id":"376042187231592452",
     "name":"RANKED (20K) #1"
  },
  {  
     "position":4,
     "id":"377805411018866688",
     "name":"RANKED (20K) #2"
  },
  {  
     "position":5,
     "id":"377805548671991829",
     "name":"RANKED (20K)-#3"
  },
  {  
     "position":0,
     "id":"376043001283084298",
     "name":"RANKED (50K) #1"
  },
  {  
     "position":1,
     "id":"377799006849466380",
     "name":"RANKED (50K) #2"
  },
  {  
     "position":2,
     "id":"377799111296155659",
     "name":"RANKED (50K) #3"
  },
  {  
     "position":9,
     "id":"376042479990079490",
     "name":"Squad #1"
  },
  {  
     "position":10,
     "id":"376042791433928744",
     "name":"Squad #2"
  },
  {  
     "position":11,
     "id":"377807672935710721",
     "name":"Squad #3"
  },
  {  
     "position":12,
     "id":"377807725934936065",
     "name":"Squad-#4"
  },
  {  
     "position":13,
     "id":"377807768800722954",
     "name":"Squad-#5"
  }
  ],
   "instant_invite":null,
   "id":"376042187231592448",
    "members":[  
     {  
     "username":"OleHead",
     "status":"online",
     "mute":false,
     "suppress":false,
     "deaf":false,
     "channel_id":"377799006849466380",
     "avatar_url":"https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/4.png",
     "avatar":null,
     "self_deaf":false,
     "discriminator":"6649",
     "self_mute":true,
     "id":"324718336682491904"
  },
  {  
     "username":"pubg-bot",
     "status":"online",
     "bot":true,
     "avatar_url":"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/304978857885171713/ef753a91fcd9cb0d7f68c2f7c829bb6e.jpg",
     "avatar":"ef753a91fcd9cb0d7f68c2f7c829bb6e",
     "discriminator":"6547",
     "id":"304978857885171713"
  },
  {  
     "username":"PUBGOnline.com",
     "status":"online",
     "bot":true,
     "game":{  
        "name":"PUBGOnline"
     },
     "avatar_url":"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/314523338401906688/09aee24f191b0cddf1ea41a8d8d63d8a.jpg",
     "avatar":"09aee24f191b0cddf1ea41a8d8d63d8a",
     "discriminator":"6968",
     "id":"314523338401906688"
  }
   ],
 "name":"PUBGMATES"
 }
```

Comment: post the full json string please, its hard to understand the format with your question.

Comment: I am on my phone now I cant get the full formatted json API. But what I am trying to do is figure out the way In which i can query the people connected to a specific channel and output it into numbers.

Comment: You probably want to loop over the members and on each iteration check if the user is connected to channel 1 and if so, add them to an array. We can't be more specific than that till you fix your formatting to show us the actual JSON. But, more importantly, you should check the docs for the API you're using, any decent API will have a way to specify that you want only members associated to channel 1.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thank you for the suggestion, I will be updating the post with the Original JSON API.

Comment: Why did you reject my edit? it's hard to understand your question, because your post is messy.

Comment: @FatemehAbdollahei I am so sorry, my intentions was not to reject your edit but to re-edit my post since i got the json API.

Answer (score 0):

The data given doesn't tell you how many people are connected to the channel. This is as much as you can do:

```
var apiData = { /* that monstrosity you just pasted */ };

for (var i = 0; i < apiData.members.length; i++) {
    if (apiData.members[i].username === "OleHead") {
        var channelId = apiData.members[i].channel_id;
        for (var c = 0; c < apiData.channels.length; c++) {
            if (apiData.channels[c].id === channelId) {

                $('#target-div').html(apiData.channels[c].name)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will change the inner HTML of `<div id="target-div"></div>` to `RANKED (50K) #2`

Unless you can find the amount of people connected to the channel in a different API call, you can't get it with the JSON you just provided.

> P.S. Bleh, Discord has some yucky API specs by the look of it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hard work and giving me an answer. I just have another question. Where about do I post this beautiful code you just given me? I am a real noob in coding.

Comment: Whatever javascript file your website is using should do the trick.

Comment: Just comment here if you have any more problems.